# Not working in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

I am trying to make a PHP page that embeds a JavaScript into the page that makes some YouTube videos on the page and so on, that works fine, but I have another script on the page that should sort these YouTube videos based on the amount of views they have. That normally works, but since I started working on PHP for the page so I don't have to hardcode everything, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<html>


<body>
<?php
$youtubeID = array("KxEhALUc_xo", "HHuOu8L5f58", "DANypN7iXsI");

$len = count($youtubeID);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $embedCode = "<script>
                    var id = ('" . $youtubeID[$i] . "')
                    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=" . $youtubeID[$i] . "&key=', function(data) {
                    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=" . $youtubeID[$i] . "&key=', function(data2) {
                        var tags = data2.items[0].snippet.tags;
                        var likes = data.items[0].statistics.likeCount;
                        var viewcount = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                        var title = data2.items[0].snippet.title;
                        var channel = data2.items[0].snippet.channelTitle;
                        $('div#videocontainer').append('<div class = videoframe><iframe src = \"https:\\\\\\\\www.youtube.com\\\\embed\\\\" . $youtubeID[$i] . "\" width = 854 height = 510 frameborder= 0 allowfullscreen></iframe><div class = countercontainer><div class = counter>View count:'+viewcount+'</div></div><div class = titlecontainer><div class = title>'+title+'</div></div><div class = likescontainer><div class = likes>'+likes+'</div></div></div>');
                        });
                    });
                </script>




    ";
    echo $embedCode;
}   

?>



<script>
$('button#viewsasc').click(function() {
    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();

    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    $('div#sortedcontainer').html($(videos));

});

$('button#viewsdesc').click(function() {

    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();

    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    $('div#sortedcontainer').html($(videos));

});
</script>

<button id = 'viewsasc'>desc</button>
<button id = 'viewsdesc'>asc</button>
<div id = 'videocontainer'></div>
<div id = 'sortedcontainer'></div>





</body>
</html>
```

I know it all looks like a mess, but its just a prototype ;).
So as you can see, I have a little array with 3 YouTube video IDs, I then try to embed a JavaScript code that will get som JSON data, make some divs, and show the video with youtubes "iframe".
That all works good, I have 3 YouTube videos showing on my page, and I have the external text with all the views, title, and likes showned.

**WHAT's not working** is this part:

```
<script>
$('button#viewsasc').click(function() {
    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();

    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    $('div#sortedcontainer').html($(videos));

});

$('button#viewsdesc').click(function() {

    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();

    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    $('div#sortedcontainer').html($(videos));

});
</script>

<button id = 'viewsasc'>desc</button>
<button id = 'viewsdesc'>asc</button>
<div id = 'videocontainer'></div>
<div id = 'sortedcontainer'></div>
```

So when i press these buttons:

```
<button id = 'viewsasc'>desc</button>
<button id = 'viewsdesc'>asc</button>
```

it will indeed move the "videoframe" div into the "sortedcontainer" div, but it is not sorted, it's just moved to another div, so that's pretty useless. Here is gyazo so you can see what i mean: https://gyazo.com/dc9baa1f1342ffc08c66b2db41d3a4d0

I am very confused by PHP and not very good at it as you can guess, there is probably some obvious rule I didn't know about, I only just started to study PHP.

Comment: This will be a tricky one to answer as it's not easy to reproduce and see what is going on, but when you say it doesn't work, are there any errors in your console ? (f12), I suspect `jquery` might not be loaded at time of `$` userage.. but hard to say

Comment: The part that is not working, needs to be added to the file after the `<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` section, if you can verify that we can try to narrow more down.

Comment: Did you open the browser console?

Comment: @TorJakobsen At this point I strongly recommend invalidating these API keys and getting new ones.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies.
@Pogrindis  there is no errors apart from "Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection:......" but i don't think that's relevant to this? Also i just learned that, that part that's not working has to be AFTER the buttons code part, otherwise it's not doing anything at all, so i can't really put that part all the way up where you want it. But now we narrowed it down to that, so i don't have to include those two codes from another PHP file. 
I will edit my post. However i still can't understand why it's just refreshing when i press the buttons, not sorting :/

Comment: wth? I eddited the post earlier like seconds after i made it so it wouldnt show the key, damn.. yeah i gotta get a new key now

Comment: Ok so i just figured out that it's probably because i use XAMPP, i just tried to basically redo the same thing in HTML where it usually works, but it didn't, then i tried to open the HTML directly, then it worked.. XAMPP is the problem, wonder why...